# Integrate Intuit Merchant Service to custom ecommerce

Tags: payment-gateway, intuit-partner-platform, merchant-account

I have a "choose subscription package" page and customers can sign up for a subscription package and pay for it.
i just want to use intuit merchant service for this and for the payment process.
i dont really need a shopping cart application since there are only 3 subscription packages and they are not dynamic.
As simple as transaction begins just by clicking the button of their preferred package.

I think i can use Keith's quickbook-devkit but i don't think i can implement it the right way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but, to answer your question: While you can use the QBMS SDK to process transactions, Intuit is completely abandoning this and replacing with "QuickBooks Payments Beta". Unfortunately, you will have to subscribe to Quickbooks Online to use it, making connecting directly to their merchant service unusable for desktop and enterprise users. 
My advice: Don't waste a minute of your time coding the old stuff. Sign up for Paypal's merchant account (they combine the 4 major credit cards and PayPal payments in a single monthly statement - then you can import it into Quickbooks manually, including actual details of say, a shopping cart).

Answer (score -1):

Use the open-source PHP DevKit here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Follow the instructions here to get set up (you should more than likely be using the DESKTOP method):

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration

Example code is here:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/merchant_services/example_merchant_service.php

It looks something like this:

```
// Now, let's create a credit card object, and authorize an amount agains the card
$name = 'Keith Palmer';
$number = '5105105105105100';
$expyear = date('Y');
$expmonth = date('m');
$address = '56 Cowles Road';
$postalcode = '06279';
$cvv = null;

// Create the CreditCard object
$Card = new QuickBooks_MerchantService_CreditCard($name, $number, $expyear, $expmonth, $address, $postalcode, $cvv);

// We're going to authorize $295.00
$amount = 295.0;

if ($Transaction = $MS->authorize($Card, $amount))
{
    print('Card authorized!' . "\n");
    print_r($Transaction);  
}
```

Some other notes:

> i dont really need a shopping cart application

Intuit does not offer a shopping cart, so that really has nothing to do with any of this.

> I think i can use Keith's quickbook-devkit but i don't think i can implement it the right way.

If you don't think so, perhaps you should provide a bit more detail. Specifically *why* don't you think you can implement it the "right" way? What is this "right" way that you're trying to implement it as?

Comment: Hi @keith, i have use the code above, and my transactions have recorded in transactions section in intuit. Does the code
    $Transaction = $MS->charge($Card, $amount)
does the charging of the card? or do i have to add to charge a wallet?
But then in the transaction sections, it always goes to a status "pending".. is this fine? but sometimes it became 'funded' and 'withheld'.. Do I need to use a working credit card number?

Comment: ->charge(...) actually charges as credit card. The "wallet" features are for if you want to store the credit card number with Intuit, for future use (e.g. if you're doing recurring billing or will charge the card again in the future). As far as the statuses go - contact Intuit, and they can tell you what the different statuses mean.

Comment: i did use the wallet for charging the card again..
Ive used this code to get the current wallet for recharging: 

     '$CreditCard = $MS->getWallet($customerID, $walletID)'

but credit card info such as number and cvv is protected, how can i use that info for the $cvv variable here to charge the wallet?

    '$Transaction = $MS->chargeWallet($customerID, $walletID, $amount, $salestax, $comment, $cvv)'

Also this code only adds the transaction under the transaction section in the intuit, can i add this under the recurring payment section?

Comment: CVV codes are *never* stored - storing a CVV code will get you banned for live from ever running Visa or Mastercard transactions again. *Do not do store them*. You *do not need* a CVV code to charge credit cards - they are optional. ->chargeWallet() charges credit cards, that's all. None of this has anything to do with the recurring payment features Intuit provides.

Comment: ok so i can use
    '$MS->chargeWallet($customerID, $walletID, $amount, $salestax)'
for charging a wallet even $cvv is not specified in the parameter?
That is awesome~

Comment: Yes. If you look at the examples, it is indicated that they are *optional*. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/merchant_services/example_merchant_service_wallet.php

Comment: Thank you so much @keith.. One more thing, Is there any code for recurring payment? a code using the method above of recharging the wallet , but will take place every month and will be recorded under the recurring payment in the intuit?

Comment: We don't have any code for recurring payments right now. Our experience has been that it's better to use a real recurring billing system like http://ChargeOver.com instead -  more flexible, integrates fully with QuickBooks, and much more feature rich.